# Probability function question - Uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

if $X∼Uc(1,8)$ and $Y=X^2$. I need to calculate $P(Y≤7)$.

So Isn't it just the cumulative uniform distribution function but to calculate $x$ first? meaning $(x-a)/(b-a)$. 
So I do $x-1/8-1$, but what's getting me confused is if I can do this -
x = $2.645$ (the square root of 7).

Comment: What is $Uc$? It means uniformly distributed? (Usually it's just $U$.)

Comment: Yes, I meant uniform continuous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(Y\leq 7)=P(-\sqrt 7 \leq X\leq \sqrt 7)=P(1 \leq X\leq \sqrt 7)$ since $X$ takes values in $(1,8)$. Hence $P(Y\leq 7)=\frac {\sqrt 7 -1} 7$.

Answer (score 2):

$$P(Y\leq 7) = P(X\leq \sqrt{7}) = \frac{\sqrt{7}-1}{8-1}=\frac{\sqrt{7}-1}{7}$$
since $X$ is positive.